# Absolute Value Subtraction of Two byte arrays in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to take the absolute value subtraction of two byte arrays that contain bytes of 2 images.
I know there is alot of complications with this whole byte subtraction situation because the "-" operator for bytes doesn't exist.

Is there some way to subtract two byte arrays from each other and store that in another byte array?

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Subtraction {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            //Read Image to a byte array
            BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new File("ground.bmp"));
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(bImage, "bmp", bos );
            byte [] data = bos.toByteArray();
            System.out.println("ground: " + data);

            BufferedImage bImage2 = ImageIO.read(new File("back.bmp"));
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(bImage2, "bmp", bos2 );
            byte [] data2 = bos2.toByteArray();
            System.out.println("Back: " + data2);

            byte [] data3 = (byte) (Math.abs(data2 - data)); // really wished this worked
            System.out.println("Subtracted Bytes: " + data3);

            ByteArrayInputStream j = new ByteArrayInputStream(data3);
            BufferedImage bImage3;
            bImage3 = ImageIO.read(j)
            ImageIO.write(bImage3, "bmp", new File("Subtracted.bmp"));
            System.out.println("image created");



     }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from byte to byte[]
    The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) byte[], byte[]
```

What I need to do is subtract two images based on bytes and get the result of it as a third image.

How can I do this with bytes?

Comment: what do you mean by subtracting two byte array

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `List::removeAll`

Comment: I am just trying to get result of the absolute value subtraction of 2 images based on bytes

Comment: *because the "-" operator for bytes doesn't exist.* I have some **wonderful** news. The `-` operator for `byte` **does *exist***.

Comment: Lit it does exist! Could you elaborate how it would work for the program above?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch OP is trying to subtract two byte arrays

Comment: @scarywombat the - operator doesn't exist for any type of array, so I'm not really sure what op means by that.

Comment: Would it be possible if I would to convert the byte into int. Then get the subtraction of those 2 ints and convert it that back to bytes.? How would you convert a byte array to an int array?

Comment: Seems to me an XY-problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to accomplish, subtraction aside? What do you expect the output image to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you have a comment by that you wished would work, one option would be to work element-wise.

```
byte [] data3 = new byte[data.length];
for(int i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
    data3[i] = (byte)Math.abs(data2[i] - data[i]);
}

System.out.println("Subtracted Bytes: " + Arrays.toString(data3));
```

This would creating a new byte array of the same length, and then assign each element by performing the subtraction.

One more thing, if you're trying to do operations on the image, the byte array you're operating on is a serialized version of a bitmap image. It has headers, that will probably get ruined by performing this subtraction. You might want to do the operation via buffered images.

```
BufferedImage bImage3 = new BufferedImage(bImage.getWidth(), bImage.getHeight(), bImage.getType());
for(int i = 0; i<bImage.getWidth(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<bImage.getHeight(); j++){
        bImage3.setRGB(i, j, Math.abs(bImage2.getRGB(i,j) - bImage.getRGB(i,j)));
    }
}
```

This could be improved by using an image op, or working on the rasters directly.

Comment: Quick Question if I would to use average instead of subtraction replacing the subtraction line with average line would it work?

Comment: Yes exactly. You could replace the setRGB to set it to all sorts of equations. The average would be `(bImage2.getRGB(i,j) + bImage3.getRGB(i,j))/2`. There could be some issues involving color though.